# How can I convert a 64 byte string to 20 byte string?

Tags: c, encryption, base64

Below is the problem statement that I have :

> I  am given a 64 byte string which can contain only digits [0-9].
>
> Need to convert the string to a 20 byte representation and also be able to decode the representation.

The option that comes to my mind is to convert the input string (which is basically a number ) to its base64(or may be higher??) representation which will reduce the size.

But C integer/double datatypes won't allow such big numbers to handle which is a bottleneck.

Also I am really doubtful whether it is even possible. If we can't convert 64 byte to 20 byte then what is the maximum number that can fit into 20 bytes.

Comment: since it can only contain digits and there are 10  different digits you can compress every char in the string to 4 bits, therefore you can place two digits into one (unsigned) byte. so you'll be able to compress to 32 bytes using a simple naive method.  
the fourth and eight bit are left a bit unused therefore you might be able to compress it even more

Comment: 20 bytes is quite hardcore. Maybe try static huffman coding.

Comment: The task doesn't make any sense. Question the specification.

Comment: Detail: In C a string _always_ contains a null character, else it is not a _string_.  So "64 byte _string_ which can contain only digits [0-9]." is not possible.  Perhaps you meant a 64-byte _string_ containing only digits characters ending with the null character?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that each byte is 8 bits.

`10^64` is greater than `2^(20*8)` so it won't really fit.

A rough guide is that 10 bits (1024 kombinations) can store 3 digits (1000).

You have 20*8 = 160 bits so you can store (slightly more than) 48 digits without loss of information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only numbers from 0 to 10 per 64 characters you need totally about 213 bits `sup( log(2,10^64) )` that are 27 byte `sup( 213/8  )`.

So **no**, you **cannot** compress that number without losing some combination in only 20 byte, 8 bit long.

Supposing you can use **27 byte** so you can split your number in block of 3: `123`, `456` and write them in binary and concatenating the binary values.

You will use totally `21 blocks * 10 bits + 4 bits` (last digit) that are 27 byte. `sup( 214/8 ) = 27`

PS. with sup() I intend the rounded number to the next integer.

Answer (score 0):

A rough heuristic is the number of bits to represent decimal digits is 3.3 or 3.3-bits ~= 1-digit.

So roughly
10^64 ~= 211-bits ~= 26-bytes
and
20-bytes = 160-bits ~= 48-digits

Thus the question is not possible.

This is (back of the envelope) close to the actual result reported by Timmy and can be done easily "in the head".

Note: by digit I mean base 10 digits.